# How to pass attributes from Cloud Scheduler to Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to trigger a Cloud Function which runs on a schedule as such:

Cloud Scheduler -> Cloud Pub/Sub -> Cloud Functions

My Cloud Function uses attributes from the Pub/Sub message:

```
    let messageTitle = null;
        try {
            messageTitle = message.attributes.messageTitle;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('no title in pub/sub message', e);
        }
```

How can I create a scheduler which has attributes?

I have tried entering this in the Scheduler 'Payload' field:

```
{
  "data": "string",
  "attributes": {
    messageTitle: "TEST 3 title",
    messageBody: "TEST 3 body"
  },
  "messageId": "string",
  "publishTime": "string"
}
```

But it does not create the attributes in Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today (july 2020), an important thing to know on Cloud Scheduler: **Few parameters are accessible through the console**.

If you want to access to advance parameter, use the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/pubsub) or the [rest API](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs/create)

Now you can access to the retry policies and to the attributes on PubSub message.

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create pubsub --message-body=my_body \
   --attributes=att1=val1,att2=val2 --topic=topicName \
   --schedule="0 0 * * *" --time-zone=UTC mySchedulerName
```

*Note, in the console, you can only define the payload, I mean the `data` field in the PubSub message, equal to the `--message-body=` in the command line*

Comment: Awesome this worked! Didn't realise the scheduler console didn't have all the functionality, thanks.